# Destroying Class member variable in a different class in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code snippet.

```
Home::Room::Room (param1, param2, param3) :
    mem_1(param1),
    mem_2(0),
    mem_3(Office::Start(param1, param2, param3),
    mem_4_cs("conn")
{
}


Office::Start(param1, param2, param3)
{
    try
    {
        success something;
    }
    catch
    {
        // throw some exception.
        // destroys the conn object "mem_4_cs" from class Home's member and create a new member object    to be used in class Home
        ~DealWithObject(); // assume there is a destructor here that does it
        DealWithObject(mem_4_cs); // Creates a new object with the new "conn" string as in class Home
    }
}
```

I am trying to destroy a member object that enters the critical section (`mem_4_cs`) in a different class (`Office`) than the one that created it (`Home`) upon failure and return a new one to the 'Home' class. Any better ways to achieve it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "destroy" the object? You don't need to destroy anything manually if it wasn't allocated dynamically. Are you sure you're not just looking to reassign `mem_4_cs` to a different value?

Comment: yes. Precisely that is what the goal is. Now mem_4_cs does get created in the Home::Room::Room constructor. But if the Office::Start () method fails, then I want to destroy mem_4_cs or create a new mem_4_cs with a new value. Basically it is a new handle to the object that enters a critical section if that makes sense.

Comment: Then you probably just want to do `mem_4_cs = newValue`. Depending on what `mem_4_cs` is, you may have to create an assignment operator for it.

Comment: `~DealWithObject();` -- Please, don't do this. It's hard to say what you're asking for without seeing what `DealWithObject` is doing, but I can guarantee you shouldn't be calling the destructor explicitly. When you say `critical section` are you referring to multi-threaded programming?

Comment: @AtlasC1 yes, I am referring to multi-threaded programing